# Turtle.goto error

Tags: python, typeerror, turtle-graphics

When I try to run this python code:

```
import turtle
coordiantes = ['(100, 100)', '(90, 20)', '(50, 45)']
turtle.goto(coordiantes[0])
```

I get this error message:

> TypeError: **new**() takes 3 positional arguments but 9 were given

What does this mean? How can I fix my code so that the `turtle` goes to a set of coordinates in the list without making 2 separate lists for x and y values?
I've already tried removing the parentheses, but it displayed the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `turtle` as well:

```
bob = turtle.Turtle()
```

Then you may use the `goto` but without strings (documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.goto)):

```
coordiantes = [(100, 100), (90, 20), (50, 45)]
bob.goto(*coordiantes[0])
```

If you want your `turtle` (bob) to follow all the coordinates you provided in the list in order you can use a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(coordinates)):
    bob.goto(*coordinates[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

`goto` is a method on a Turtle instance so you need to first instantiate a Turtle instance and then pass in two numbers (X, Y) to the `goto` method.

```
from turtle import Turtle
t = Turtle()
coordiantes = [(100, 100), (90, 20), (50, 45)]
t.goto(*coordiantes[0])
```

If you're reading from the documentation, notice the description [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#methods-of-rawturtle-turtle-and-corresponding-functions):

> Most of the examples in this section refer to a Turtle instance called
>   turtle.